# How would a Buddhist advise on this subset of problems of motivation?

Tags: personal-practice, psychology, motivation, emotion

Some call Buddhism psychology, so maybe it can help -- me.

This sense that doing something -- let's take a difficult but generic example, learning sanskrit -- is a wonderful, exciting idea; but one never gets started with it, because there is no tangible psychological or material benefit from it -- for whatever reason [you won't find anyone new to talk with, most texts are in translation, no-one will care, etc.].

What remedy is there for this?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Are you asking about a remedy for lack of motivation?

Comment: yes, but i am also describing exactly what sort of lack of motivation i mean @Erik

Comment: or at least framing it

Comment: Nyom likes to know reasonings for learn worldly skills, maybe languages, right?

Comment: You seem to be thinking clearly. What are you trying to find a remedy for? Is there some part of you that thinks you should learn Sanskrit? .

Comment: @PeterJ motivational problems [both apathy and -- mild -- depression] are not limited to people who can't think straight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the article "[Two Exercises for Turning Intention into Motivation](https://tricycle.org/trikedaily/thupten-jinpa-motivation/)" by Thupten Jinpa on Buddhist site tricycle.org, we see some useful tips on how to motivate yourself to do a task that you set yourself to do.

He states that "parents who have struggled with their child taking up a new instrument will recognize how everything changed the moment the child began enjoying it." Basically you need to find a way to enjoy what you're doing - this is intrinsic motivation. When you enjoy it, the rest comes naturally.

You can try the two exercises on this page.

> The question of how we motivate ourselves to pursue our deeper
>   aspirations has been a major interest in the long history of Buddhist
>   psychology. In Buddhist thinking, motivation is a matter of desire,
>   more specifically the **desire to act** accompanied with a sense of
>   **purpose**. Say, in the case of being more compassionate, it’s by making
>   emotional connection with compassion and its objectives that we arouse
>   in ourselves the desire to act. And it’s through seeing the benefits
>   that we acquire a sense of purpose in being more compassionate.
>
> Contemporary psychology has only relatively recently come to
>   appreciate the role of emotions in motivating our behavior. For a long
>   time, the Western theory of action was dominated by rational choice
>   theory, and emotions were accused of clouding the process rather than
>   being an integral part of the system. To articulate the dual dimension
>   of our motivation—cognitive awareness of **and** emotional connection with
>   our goals—Buddhist psychology uses a term that is almost impossible to
>   capture in any single word in English. The Sanskrit term *shraddha*
>   (*depa* in Tibetan) has a broad range of meaning, the important ones
>   being “faith,” “trust,” “belief,” or “confidence,” connoting
>   “appreciation” and “admiration” as well. *Shraddha* is a felt sense like
>   trust, rather than a cognitive state like belief or knowledge.
>   Experientially, *shraddha* feels something like attachment or attraction
>   to our goal, like being inspired to play guitar when you see a rock
>   star do it. It’s this quality, *shraddha*, that primes our heart and
>   mind to roll up our sleeves and play.
>
> How do we tap our emotional reservoir? Cognitions play a critical
>   role, which the early Buddhist texts characterize as **seeing** the value
>   of doing something. Through cognitive engagement, such as seeing the
>   benefits, we connect intention with motivation. So, within this causal
>   nexus, the crucial link to watch for is the one between our awareness
>   of the goal and why we would go for it, our feelings about the goal,
>   and our desire or will to pursue it.
>
> Then, again, it’s the joy we take in our efforts—the courage to try,
>   the dedication to stick with it—and their results that helps sustain
>   our motivations over the long run. Or, in other words, makes us want
>   to keep trying and keep doing it. **Parents who have struggled with
>   their child taking up a new instrument will recognize how everything
>   changed the moment the child began enjoying it.** This is called
>   **intrinsic** motivation, as opposed to the **extrinsic** motivation of, for
>   example, the parent rewarding the child with more screen time for
>   practicing her instrument. From decades of motivation research, we
>   know that **intrinsic motivation is far more stable and enduring**. The
>   process of setting intentions and joyfully reflecting on them in
>   dedication is how, over time, we transform extrinsic into intrinsic
>   motivations, and thereby sustain the energy and purpose to live true
>   to our best aspirations.

Comment: incidentally, my mother suggested lower your expectations -- it won't be as motivating as you think. thanks

Comment: @sorta_buddhist My music teacher told me he wanted me to practice for *five minutes* every day -- that 5 minutes a day of practice is better than half an hour once per week -- and I can't say "I don't have time" to practice for just 5 minutes. He also set me to learning (enjoyable) tunes rather than (boring) exercises like playing scales. When I did, then I found my skill improved, not day by day but week by week -- and that (success) enables motivation to continue.

Comment: just to add -- might it be and the answer link to something about the need for shared -- rather than personal -- meaning?

Answer (score 1):

According to Buddhism, faith in something is the foundation of motivation.

> he places conviction in him. With the arising of conviction, he visits him & grows close to him. Growing close to him, he lends ear. Lending ear, he hears the Dhamma. Hearing the Dhamma, he remembers it. Remembering it, he penetrates the meaning of those dhammas. Penetrating the meaning, he comes to an agreement through pondering those dhammas. There being an agreement through pondering those dhammas, desire arises. With the arising of desire, he becomes willing. Willing, he contemplates (lit: "weighs," "compares"). Contemplating, he makes an exertion. Exerting himself, he both realizes the ultimate meaning of the truth with his body and sees by penetrating it with discernment.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.095x.than.html